# MySQL multiple SUM returning same value

Tags: mysql, select, join, sum

I have a "bloomp" (like a post), when I select it from the database, I SUM the number of comments, likes and if the current user liked.

The problem is with the number of likes and comments. For example:

If the bloomp has 3 likes and 1 comment, the select return that it has 3 likes and 3 comments, and vice-versa.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT `bloomps`.`id` AS id,
       `bloomps`.`text` AS text,
       `bloomps`.`date` AS date,
       `images`.`id` AS image_id,
       `videos`.`id` AS video_id,
       `videos`.`provider` AS video_provider,
       `users`.`name` AS author_name,
       `users`.`picture` AS author_picture,
       SUM(CASE WHEN likes.bloomp_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS likes_number,
       SUM(CASE WHEN likes.bloomp_id IS NOT NULL AND likes.author_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS liked,
       SUM(CASE WHEN comments.bloomp_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS comments_number
FROM (`bloomps`)
INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `bloomps`.`author_id`
LEFT JOIN `likes` ON `likes`.`bloomp_id` = `bloomps`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`bloomp_id` = `bloomps`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `images` ON `images`.`bloomp_id` = `bloomps`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `videos` ON `videos`.`bloomp_id` = `bloomps`.`id`
GROUP BY `bloomps`.`id`
ORDER BY `bloomps`.`id` ASC
LIMIT 10
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

This query:

```
SELECT `bloomps`.`id` AS id,
       `bloomps`.`text` AS text,
       `bloomps`.`date` AS date,
       `users`.`name` AS author_name,
       `users`.`picture` AS author_picture,
       SUM(CASE WHEN likes.bloomp_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS likes_number,
       SUM(CASE WHEN likes.bloomp_id IS NOT NULL AND likes.author_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS liked,
       SUM(CASE WHEN comments.bloomp_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS comments_number
FROM (`bloomps`)
INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `bloomps`.`author_id`
LEFT JOIN `likes` ON `likes`.`bloomp_id` = `bloomps`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`bloomp_id` = `bloomps`.`id`
GROUP BY `bloomps`.`id`
ORDER BY `bloomps`.`id` ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Is returning:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [text] => All these years I've been feeling like I was growing into myself. Finally, I feel grown.
            [date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [image_id] => 
            [video_id] => yfg8CMWeUAU
            [video_provider] => youtube
            [author_name] => Claudius Ibn
            [author_picture] => 356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab.jpg
            [likes_number] => 10
            [liked] => 5
            [comments_number] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [text] => Reveal not every secret you have to a friend, for how can you tell but that friend may hereafter become an enemy. And bring not all mischief you are able to upon an enemy, for he may one day become your friend.
            [date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [image_id] => 356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab.jpg
            [video_id] => 
            [video_provider] => 
            [author_name] => Elza Virginia
            [author_picture] => 77de68daecd823babbb58edb1c8e14d7106e83bb.jpg
            [likes_number] => 6
            [liked] => 6
            [comments_number] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [text] => To me, old age is always 15 years older than I am.
            [date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [image_id] => 41025046575248278_WzB3wKD0_f.jpg
            [video_id] => 
            [video_provider] => 
            [author_name] => Elza Virginia
            [author_picture] => 77de68daecd823babbb58edb1c8e14d7106e83bb.jpg
            [likes_number] => 1
            [liked] => 1
            [comments_number] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [text] => Accept the pain, cherish the joys, resolve the regrets; then can come the best of benedictions - 'If I had my life to live over, I'd do it all the same.
            [date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [image_id] => 
            [video_id] => 
            [video_provider] => 
            [author_name] => Claudio Cardozo
            [author_picture] => da4b9237bacccdf19c0760cab7aec4a8359010b0.jpg
            [likes_number] => 0
            [liked] => 0
            [comments_number] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [text] => Be master of your petty annoyances and conserve your energies for the big, worthwhile things. It isn't the mountain ahead that wears you out - it's the grain of sand in your shoe.
            [date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [image_id] => 4889470_700b.jpg
            [video_id] => 
            [video_provider] => 
            [author_name] => Claudius Ibn
            [author_picture] => 356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab.jpg
            [likes_number] => 1
            [liked] => 1
            [comments_number] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [text] => I think we're having fun. I think our customers really like our products. And we're always trying to do better.
            [date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [image_id] => 
            [video_id] => 
            [video_provider] => 
            [author_name] => Claudius Ibn
            [author_picture] => 356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab.jpg
            [likes_number] => 0
            [liked] => 0
            [comments_number] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [text] => [Addiction's] not about placating the bad dog - it's about feeding the good dog. You still have to feed the bad dog, but only enough so that the ASPCA doesn't bring you up on charges.
            [date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [image_id] => 
            [video_id] => 
            [video_provider] => 
            [author_name] => Claudius Ibn
            [author_picture] => 356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab.jpg
            [likes_number] => 0
            [liked] => 0
            [comments_number] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [text] => I've been on a diet for two weeks and all I've lost is two weeks.
            [date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [image_id] => 
            [video_id] => 
            [video_provider] => 
            [author_name] => Claudio Cardozo
            [author_picture] => da4b9237bacccdf19c0760cab7aec4a8359010b0.jpg
            [likes_number] => 1
            [liked] => 1
            [comments_number] => 0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [text] => A book burrows into your life in a very profound way because the experience of reading is not passive.
            [date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [image_id] => 
            [video_id] => 
            [video_provider] => 
            [author_name] => Elza Virginia
            [author_picture] => 77de68daecd823babbb58edb1c8e14d7106e83bb.jpg
            [likes_number] => 1
            [liked] => 1
            [comments_number] => 0
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [text] => Touch your customer, and you're halfway there.
            [date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [image_id] => 4878040_460s_v1.jpg
            [video_id] => 
            [video_provider] => 
            [author_name] => Claudius Ibn
            [author_picture] => 356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab.jpg
            [likes_number] => 0
            [liked] => 0
            [comments_number] => 0
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [text] => I know starting careers in troubled times is a challenge, but it is also a privilege. Because it's moments like these that force us to try harder, dig deeper and to discover gifts we never knew we had. To find the greatness that lies within each of us. So don't ever shy away from that endeavor. Don't stop adding to your body of work. I can promise that you will be the better for that continued effort as will be this nation that we all love.
            [date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [image_id] => 20547742019404735_U0zJkj83_f.jpg
            [video_id] => 
            [video_provider] => 
            [author_name] => Elza Virginia
            [author_picture] => 77de68daecd823babbb58edb1c8e14d7106e83bb.jpg
            [likes_number] => 0
            [liked] => 0
            [comments_number] => 0
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [text] => Misery no longer loves company. Nowadays it insists on it.
            [date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [image_id] => 
            [video_id] => 
            [video_provider] => 
            [author_name] => Elza Virginia
            [author_picture] => 77de68daecd823babbb58edb1c8e14d7106e83bb.jpg
            [likes_number] => 0
            [liked] => 0
            [comments_number] => 1
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [text] => A good novel tells us the truth about its hero; but a bad novel tells us the truth about its author.
            [date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [image_id] => 4887752_460s.jpg
            [video_id] => 
            [video_provider] => 
            [author_name] => Elza Virginia
            [author_picture] => 77de68daecd823babbb58edb1c8e14d7106e83bb.jpg
            [likes_number] => 0
            [liked] => 0
            [comments_number] => 0
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [text] => Acting is the most minor of gifts and not a very high-class way to earn a living. After all, Shirley Temple could do it at the age of four.
            [date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [image_id] => 
            [video_id] => 
            [video_provider] => 
            [author_name] => Claudius Ibn
            [author_picture] => 356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab.jpg
            [likes_number] => 0
            [liked] => 0
            [comments_number] => 0
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [text] => The time to repair the roof is when the sun is shining.
            [date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [image_id] => 
            [video_id] => 
            [video_provider] => 
            [author_name] => Claudius Ibn
            [author_picture] => 356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab.jpg
            [likes_number] => 0
            [liked] => 0
            [comments_number] => 0
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [text] => I am doomed to an eternity of compulsive work. No set goal achieved satisfies. Success only breeds a new goal. The golden apple devoured has seeds. It is endless.
            [date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [image_id] => 
            [video_id] => 5431060
            [video_provider] => vimeo
            [author_name] => Claudio Cardozo
            [author_picture] => da4b9237bacccdf19c0760cab7aec4a8359010b0.jpg
            [likes_number] => 0
            [liked] => 0
            [comments_number] => 0
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [text] => In every American there is an air of incorrigible innocence, which seems to conceal a diabolical cunning.
            [date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [image_id] => image18.png
            [video_id] => 
            [video_provider] => 
            [author_name] => Claudius Ibn
            [author_picture] => 356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab.jpg
            [likes_number] => 1
            [liked] => 1
            [comments_number] => 0
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [text] => Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not one bit simpler.
            [date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [image_id] => 
            [video_id] => 
            [video_provider] => 
            [author_name] => Claudius Ibn
            [author_picture] => 356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab.jpg
            [likes_number] => 0
            [liked] => 0
            [comments_number] => 0
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [text] => When I only begin to read, I forget I'm on this world. It lifts me on wings with high thoughts.
            [date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [image_id] => 
            [video_id] => 
            [video_provider] => 
            [author_name] => Claudio Cardozo
            [author_picture] => da4b9237bacccdf19c0760cab7aec4a8359010b0.jpg
            [likes_number] => 0
            [liked] => 0
            [comments_number] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Can you remove some of the joins? Drop the users and images and videos joins. What happens then? (dropping the associated parts of the select, of course)

Comment: I removed the images and videos joins, but the error persists.

Comment: Don't use `SUM(CASE WHEN likes.bloomp_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`. The `COUNT(likes.bloomp_id)` is simpler and probably more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have joined more than one tables to the main (bloomps) table and all these have 1-to-many relationship with it. The result is a mini-cartesian join and wrong counts when grouping.

You need to group each one separately in subqueries and then join these to the base table - and no grouping there. Try this:

```
SELECT 
    b.id
  , b.*                                -- whatever column from `bloomps`
  , COALESCE(l.cnt,0)   AS likes_number,
  , COALESCE(l.liked,0) AS liked,
  , COALESCE(c.cnt,0)   AS comments_number
FROM 
      bloomps AS b
   LEFT JOIN 
      ( SELECT bloomp_id
             , COUNT(*) AS cnt 
             , COUNT(CASE WHEN author_id = 1 THEN 1 END) AS liked
        FROM likes
        GROUP BY bloomp_id
      ) AS l
         ON l.bloomp_id = b.id
   LEFT JOIN 
      ( SELECT bloomp_id
             , COUNT(*) AS cnt 
        FROM comments
        GROUP BY bloomp_id
      ) AS c
         ON c.bloomp_id = b.id
                                         -- no need for GROUP BY
ORDER BY id ASC 
  LIMIT 10 ;
```

---

If you don't want subqueries, you could keep the query with the modifications below. Test which one is more efficient:

```
SELECT 
    b.id
  , b.test
  , b.date 
  , COUNT(DISTINCT l.id)  AS likes_number,
  , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN l.author=1 THEN l.id END) AS liked,
  , COUNT(DISTINCT c.id)  AS comments_number
FROM 
      bloomps AS b
   LEFT JOIN 
      likes AS l
         ON l.bloomp_id = b.id
   LEFT JOIN 
      comments AS c
         ON c.bloomp_id = b.id
GROUP BY b.id ASC                  -- MySQL non-standard syntax for
                                   -- GROUP BY b.id 
                                   -- ORDER BY b.id ASC 
  LIMIT 10 ;
```

Comment: I changed what is inside the `COUNT()`. Can you see the [answer's revisions?](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11809753/revisions)

Comment: Don't forget to measure performance and check the execution plans that indexes are used. The subqueries version may be faster :)

Comment: I had never considered using a SELECT statement in a JOIN - what a fantastic idea.

Answer (score 1):

The other joins are messing up your count.  For example, let's say one *bloomp* has two videos and two comments; as currently written, your query will return 4 rows, making it looks like there are 4 comments.  To fix it, either remove all the other stuff (see below), or add it to the Group By clause.

This should give you the basic info -- ID, as well as comments and likes:

```
SELECT `bloomps`.`id` AS id,
   SUM(CASE WHEN likes.bloomp_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS likes_number,
   SUM(CASE WHEN comments.bloomp_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS comments_number
FROM (`bloomps`)
LEFT JOIN `likes` ON `likes`.`bloomp_id` = `bloomps`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`bloomp_id` = `bloomps`.`id`
GROUP BY `bloomps`.`id`
ORDER BY `bloomps`.`id` ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATES :

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.likes_number, table2.comments_number FROM
    (SELECT b.id AS id, SUM(IF(l.bloomp_id IS NULL,0,1) 
     FROM bloomps b LEFT JOIN likes l ON b.id = l.bloomp_id GROUP BY b.id) AS table1
JOIN
    (SELECT b.id AS id, SUM(IF(c.bloomp_id IS NULL,0,1))
     FROM bloomps b LEFT JOIN comments c ON b.id = c.bloomp_id GROUP BY b.id) AS table2
ON table1.id = table2.id 
ORDER BY table1.id ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Well, can you post the number? or some example of your datas if you don't mind?

Comment: @ClaudiusIbn I see, I've updated my answer. Please try it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it possible running this query with no subqueries?