# Multiple counts with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a site with images and tags on the images (à la Facebook). Images are in albums.

The important bits of the DB structure are as follows

```
user: id INT
album: id INT, user_id INT
photo: id INT, album_id INT
tag: id INT, photo_id
```

I'm trying to get a call working that'll return, given a user_id, the album id, the total number of photos in that album, and the total tags in that album.

It's working fine to get either the total photos or the total tags, but not both. In that case, it returns the total number of tags twice.

The following is my SQL call:

```
SELECT album.id, COUNT(photo.id), COUNT(tag.id) 
FROM album 
LEFT OUTER JOIN photo ON (album.id = photo.album_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tag ON (photo.id = tag.photo_id) 
WHERE album.user_id = 123 GROUP BY album.id 
ORDER BY album.id DESC LIMIT 0,25
```

Any ideas how I could do this better?

Comment: Are you really joining to photo twice, or is that a typo?

Comment: Similar problem: [MySQL multiple SUM returning same value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787323/mysql-multiple-sum-returning-same-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a DISTINCT to the count

ie:

```
   COUNT(DISTINCT photo.id),
   COUNT(DISTINCT tag.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  album.id AS album_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT photo.id) AS count_photos,
  COUNT(DISTINCT tag,id) AS count_tags
FROM album 
LEFT JOIN photo ON album.id=photo.album_id 
LEFT JOIN photo ON photo.id=tag.photo_id
WHERE album.user_id = 123
GROUP BY album.id
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you have is because you are joining along two different dimensions, photos and tags.  Although COUNT(DISTINCT) works for counts, you might want to aggregate other information as well.

The more general approach is to separate the results into subqueries:

```
SELECT a.id, NumPhotos, NumTags
FROM (select album.id, count(*) as NumPhotos
      from album LEFT OUTER JOIN
           photo
           ON (album.id = photo.album_id)
     ) a  LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (select album.id, count(*) as NumTags
      from album LEFT OUTER JOIN
           photo
           ON (album.id = photo.album_id)  LEFT OUTER JOIN
           tag
           ON (photo.id = tag.photo_id)
     ) b
     on a.id = b.id
WHERE a.user_id = 123
ORDER BY a.id DESC
LIMIT 0,25
```